# Importing modules is consuming too much memory

Tags: python, memory, profiling, python-import

I have a pretty big application, that uses a lot of different libraries.
The result is that memory consumption is a bit high. Just an import of python pandas consumes over 50mb on my system. In total, the process needs more than 200mb to run. That's too much, especially if multiple processes are started.

Is there some way to optimize memory consumption? Or is it normal that just an import of python pandas already needs more than 50 MB?

Comment: You might consider importing specific functions from these large libraries. Perhaps that would help reduce your memory footprint?

Comment: Yes, I thought about it as well. Guess could optimize it a bit. Actually was a bit surprised that just the imports consumed so much memory. I think I could bring it to 100mb but for some usescases, even that is a bit too much.